# How do I change the background color of empty cells in a table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have four columns in a table that need to have red background for only fields that are empty. The database I'm editing has one class (.data) for all the columns, so I don't know if I need to add individual classes to each column to make it work or if there is a way through jQuery for it to differentiate between the blank cells and change the background color in only four columns of the table.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, you want to make the empty cells background color red?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your issue, [you can accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234). Then you can also upvote one or several answers with the gray up-arrow.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way of doing it would be:

```
$("td:empty").css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is really easy:

- For each `<td>` in the table
- If the `<td>` contains no text
- Change the `backgroundColor` in red

This gives that:

```
$('td').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == '') {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    }
});
```

Another shorter way which uses the power of jQuery selectors:

```
$('td:empty').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

It's the same thing, just shorter.

To finish, you can meet a special case: if your code is indenting with whitespaces, even if your `<td>` contains no text, jQuery will say that your `<td>` is not empty. To solve this case, use this small code:

```
$('td').text( $.trim( $('td').text() ) );
```

`$.trim()` removes useless whitespaces.

[Try this demo to understand](http://jsfiddle.net/rHQnj/1).

In your case, apply it like that:

```
$('td').each(function () {
    $(this).text( $.trim( $(this).text() ) );
    if ($(this).text() == '') {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    }
});
```